# Backup & restore to different servers different locations

Tags: sql-server, backup, restore

I need to back up hundreds of databases and restore them to 20 different servers, and different data file locations for destination servers.

Are there any tool that allows me to copy one database/all databases easily?

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Kin [dbatools](https://dbatools.io/getting-started/) you can either use [Start-DbaMigration](https://dbatools.io/functions/Start-DbaMigration/) or [Copy-DbaDatabase](https://dbatools.io/functions/copy-dbadatabase/) depending on your needs.

**Update**: Now, you can migrate from one server to many. This applies to both Start-DbaMigration and all of the Copy-Dba* commands, including Copy-DbaDatabase and Copy-DbaLogin - see https://dbatools.io/migration-enhancements/